# manage projects with Scrumpoker

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I wrote a page with Laravel to manage projects with Scrumpoker through blade syntax with controllers, models and Vue.js.

My problem is that I wrote the actual Scrumpoker in a single file.php file and it is loading by using a method through an onclick event of a form.

Now I want to split it up, make some refactoring and implement in my clean written .php Laravel files. I am doing this because it does not fetch every picture of my /storage folder correctly and to create a clean project.

Here is the code (only index.php + images folder with /themes/decksize/13plus1 or /themes/decksize/6plus1 with a.png/b.png/std.png sliced up in single pictures)

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['name']) && ($_GET['name'] == "UserDebug" ||
    substr($_GET['name'], 0, 4) == "tata")) {
    exit;
}


if (isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] == '') {
    // user is observer
    unset($_GET['name']);
}

if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $_GET['name'] = strip_tags($_GET['name']);
}
define('IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS', 5);
define('IDLE_TIMEOUT_DELETE_SECONDS', 25);
define('PATH_TO_DATA_FILE', './storage/rooms');
define('LOCKFILE', './scrumlock');
define('DEBUG', false);


if (!isset($_GET['decksize'])) {
    $decksize = '13plus1';

} else {
    $decksize = $_GET['decksize'];
    $_SESSION['decksize'] = $decksize;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['decksize'])) {
    $_SESSION['decksize'] = $decksize;
}


// valid cards - order is the same for the theme png-files
$validOptions = array(
    '13plus1' => array(
        "1" => "[ 0 ]",
        "2" => "[ 1/2 ]",
        "3" => "[ 1 ]",
        "4" => "[ 2 ]",
        "5" => "[ 3 ]",
        "6" => "[ 5 ]",
        "7" => "[ 8 ]",
        "8" => "[ 13 ]",
        "9" => "[ 20 ]",
        "10" => "[ 40 ]",
        "11" => "[ 100 ]",
        "12" => "[ ? ]",
        "13" => "[ C ]",
        // 14 => backside of card
    ),
    '6plus1' => array(
        "1" => "[ 1 ] Piece of cake",
        "2" => "[ 3 ] Hexenwerk",
        "3" => "[ 8 ] Raketenwissenschaft",
        "4" => "[ 100 ] O M G !",
        "5" => "[ ? ] Ich brauche mehr details",
        "6" => "[ C ] Kaffeepause",
        // 7 => backside of card
    ),
);

// will be used to slice the theme.png image into x slices - one per card
define('CARDS_IN_THEME', sizeof($validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']]) + 1);


function dbg($str)
{
    if (DEBUG) {
        echo $str;
    }
}

// set standard theme if no theme is set
if (!isset($_GET['theme'])) {
    $_GET['theme'] = 'A';
}

// players name matches tablename? == admin
$admin = false;
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['table']) && $_GET['name'] == $_GET['table']) {
    $admin = true;
}

// calculate card width, height and check if theme is available on disk
$offsets = getCardOffset("1", $validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']], $_GET['theme']);
if (is_array($offsets)) {
    $cardWidth = $offsets[1];
    $placeWidth = 20 + $offsets[1];
    $cardHeight = $offsets[2];
    $placeHeight = 20 + $offsets[2];
} else {
    $cardWidth = 50;
    $placeWidth = 100;
    $cardHeight = 75;
    $placeHeight = 95;
}


// Handle AJAX requests
// new players come here, their cards or ajax-commands to reset the table
if (isset($_GET['table']) && isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    // tabledata is stored in a file named same as table within /tmp
    // for security - prevent writing to other directories than /tmp by stripping all dots and slashes
    $table = str_replace(array('.', '/'), '', $_GET['table']);

    // create a new game if the player is admin and no game exists
    if (!file_exists(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table) && $admin) {
        touch(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table);
    }

    // stop all players on playing on non existing tables
    // ajax requests to non existing tables stop here
    if (!file_exists(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table)) {
        echo 'Table does not exist.';
        exit;
    }

    // making sure just ONE player fiddles arround with the array on the disk at the same time
    while (!@mkdir(LOCKFILE)) {
        sleep(2);
    }

    // read the tabledata from file
    $filedata = unserialize(file_get_contents(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table));
    if (!is_array($filedata)) {
        $filedata = array();
    }

    // kill the game if requested
    if (isset($_GET['kill']) && $admin) {
        $filedata = array();
        unlink(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table);
        echo "table killed.";
        rmdir(LOCKFILE);
        exit;
    }

    // initiate new game when not done yet
    if (!isset($filedata['table'])) {
        $filedata['table'] = array();
    }
    if (!isset($filedata['history'])) {
        $filedata['history'] = array();
    }
    if (!isset($filedata['message'])) {
        $filedata['message'] = 'Welcome to Scrummy:';
    }

    // split game array in sub parts
    $tabledata = $filedata['table']; // array of the current game (on the red blanket)
    $tabledatahistory = $filedata['history']; // array holding previous game arrays (below the red blanket)
    $players = $filedata['players']; // array holding last seen timestamps for players
    $message = $filedata['message']; // message of the table


    if (isset($_GET['options']) && $_GET['options']) {
        // override message for the table  
        if (strpos($_GET['options'], 'https://it.ly/2NDNWF8') !== false) {
            $_GET['options']
                =
                '<A href="' . $_GET['options'] . '" target="_blank">' . str_replace(
                    'https://it.ly/2NDNWF8',
                    '',
                    $_GET['options']
                ) . '</A>';
        }
        $filedata['message'] = $_GET['options'];
        $message = $filedata['message'];
        file_put_contents(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table, serialize($filedata));
    }

    // check for user manipulation
    $userIsSpoofingArround = false;
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['ID']) && $tabledata[$_GET['name']]['ID'] != $_GET['ID']) {
        $userIsSpoofingArround = true;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($tabledata[$_GET['name']]) && $userIsSpoofingArround) {
        if ((time() - $players[$_GET['name']]) < IDLE_TIMEOUT_DELETE_SECONDS) {
            dbg("[" . $tabledata[$_GET['name']]['ID'] . "] == [" . $_GET['ID'] . "]<br>");
            echo 'AUTHENTICATION PROBLEM - FRAUD DETECTED!';
            rmdir(LOCKFILE);
            exit;
        } else {
            // user is spoofing another user who idled out. user can take the session
            if ($_GET['ID']) {
                $tabledata[$_GET['name']]['ID'] = $_GET['ID'];
                dbg("updating ID<br>");
            }
        }
    } else {
        //        echo "[".$tabledata[$_GET['name']]['ID']."] == [".$_GET['ID']."]<br>";
    }


    // put the current game into the history
    if (isset($_GET['add']) && $admin) {
        $tabledatahistory[] = $tabledata;
        $tabledata = array();
        $filedata['table'] = $tabledata;
        $filedata['history'] = $tabledatahistory;
        file_put_contents(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table, serialize($filedata));
        rmdir(LOCKFILE);
        exit;
    }

    // set a card for a player if all _GET data is valid
    if (
        isset($_GET['guess']) && $_GET['guess'] != '' && isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name']
        && isset($tabledata[$_GET['name']])
        && $tabledata[$_GET['name']]['ID'] == $_GET['ID']
    ) {
        if (in_array($_GET['guess'], array_keys($validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']]))) {
            dbg("saving guess and updating time<br>");
            $tabledata[$_GET['name']] = array('name' => $_GET['name'], 'guess' => $_GET['guess'], 'ID' => $_GET['ID']);
            $players[$_GET['name']] = time();
        }
    }

    // recognition of new player without a card - prepare slot
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && !isset($tabledata[$_GET['name']]) && isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name']) {
        $tabledata[$_GET['name']] = array('name' => $_GET['name'], 'guess' => '...', 'ID' => $_GET['ID']);
        dbg("adding new player with guess ...<br>");
    }

    // drop ideling players after IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($tabledata[$_GET['name']]) && $_GET['name'] && !$userIsSpoofingArround) {
        $players[$_GET['name']] = time();
        dbg("updating time<br>");
    }

    // combine history and current game into one array
    $filedata['table'] = $tabledata;
    $filedata['history'] = $tabledatahistory;
    $filedata['players'] = $players;
    $filedata['message'] = $message;

    // write table data to disk
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name']) {
        file_put_contents(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table, serialize($filedata));
        dbg("writing data to disk<br>");
    }

    // prepare layout of the webpage
    // show all cards
    $showAllCards = true;

    // echo table header with names
    ksort($players);
    $playernames = array();
    if (is_array($players)) {
        $playernames = array_keys($players);
    }

    $totalPlayers = 0;
    $activePlayers = 0;
    $playersOnTable = 0;
    // check if some players did not choose yet
    if (is_array($playernames)) {
        foreach ($playernames as $eachPlayername) {
            $totalPlayers++;
            if ((time() - $players[$eachPlayername]) < IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS) {
                $activePlayers++;
            }
            if ((time() - $players[$eachPlayername]) < IDLE_TIMEOUT_DELETE_SECONDS) {
                $playersOnTable++;
            }
            if (
                $tabledata[$eachPlayername]['guess'] == '...'
                && (time() - $players[$eachPlayername]) < IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS
            ) {
                $showAllCards = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // automatic new row
    if ($showAllCards && $activePlayers > 1) {
        $tabledatahistory[] = $tabledata;
        //$tabledata = array();  <-- will not work - enables session hijacking
        foreach ($tabledata as $username => $userarray) {
            $tabledata[$username]['guess'] = '...';
        }
        $filedata['table'] = $tabledata;
        $filedata['history'] = $tabledatahistory;
        file_put_contents(PATH_TO_DATA_FILE . $table, serialize($filedata));
    }
    rmdir(LOCKFILE);

    echo '<A href="javascript:clearTimeout(TIMEOUT)">Take A Break(STOP REFRESH)</A><br><br>';
    echo '<h2>' . $message . '</h2>';

    echo '<style>
     .striped-border {
        border: 1px dashed #000;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
    }
    hr {
        height: 1px;
        color: #123455;
        background-color: #123455;
        border: none;
    }
    .center {
        margin: auto;
        width: 60%;
        border: 15px solid #000000;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center
      }
      </style>
     <div class=center>Players On Table: ' . $playersOnTable . "<br>";


    echo 'Total Player:' . $totalPlayers . "<br>";
    echo 'Active Players: ' . $activePlayers . "<br>";
    echo '<div class="header">';
    if (is_array($playernames)) {
        foreach ($playernames as $eachPlayerName) {
            $id = '(' . $tabledata[$eachPlayerName]['ID'] . '/' . $_GET['ID'] . ')';
            $id = '';
            if (time() - $players[$eachPlayerName] < IDLE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS) {
                echo '<div class="place" style="text-align:left"' . $placeWidth . 'px;overflow:hidden">' . '<strong>' . 'Player:' . '</strong>' . ' ' . $eachPlayerName . '<br>' ./*'<b>'.hash('sha512',session_id($eachPlayerName)).'</b>'.*/ $id
                    . '</div>';
            } elseif (time() - $players[$eachPlayerName] < IDLE_TIMEOUT_DELETE_SECONDS) {
                echo '<div class="place" style="width:' . $placeWidth . 'px;overflow:hidden">' . $eachPlayerName . $id
                    . '<br><i>INACTIVE</i></div>';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>';


        // CURRENT TABLE
        echo '<div class="currentTable" style="width:' . ($playersOnTable * $placeWidth) . '"><nobr>';
        foreach ($playernames as $eachPlayerName) {
            $styleaddon = '';

            $ownPlace = (isset($_GET['name']) && $tabledata[$eachPlayerName]['name'] == $_GET['name']);
            $playerPlayedACard = ($tabledata[$eachPlayerName]['guess'] != '...');
            if (time() - $players[$eachPlayerName] < IDLE_TIMEOUT_DELETE_SECONDS) {
                echo '<div class="place"><center>';
                $offsets = getCardOffset($tabledata[$eachPlayerName]['guess'], $validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']], $_GET['theme']);
                if (is_array($offsets)) {
                    // show nifty cards
                    echo '' . (($showAllCards || ($ownPlace && $playerPlayedACard))
                        ?
                        // show card face up
                        '<div style="width:' . $cardWidth . ';height:' . $cardHeight . ';background-image:url(\'/storage/'
                        . $offsets[3] . '\');background-position:' . $offsets[0] . ' 0px;">&nbsp;</div>'
                        : ($playerPlayedACard
                            ?
                            // show card face down
                            '<div style="width:' . $cardWidth . ';height:' . $cardHeight
                            . ';background-image:url(\'' . $offsets[3] . '\');background-position:'
                            . (-(CARDS_IN_THEME - 1) * $cardWidth) . 'px 0px;">&nbsp;</div>'
                            :
                            // show empty place
                            '<div style="' . $styleaddon . 'width:' . $cardWidth . ';height:' . $cardHeight
                            . ';overflow:hidden;">&nbsp;</div>')) . '';

                } else {
                    // theme not found or erroneous - show text cards
                    echo '' . (($showAllCards || ($ownPlace && $playerPlayedACard))
                        ?
                        // show card face up
                        '<div class="card"><span style="height:' . $cardHeight
                        . 'px; width:1px; vertical-align:middle"></span>'
                        . $validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']][$tabledata[$eachPlayerName]['guess']] . '</div>'
                        : ($playerPlayedACard
                            ?
                            // show card face down
                            '<img src="/storage/images/back.jpg?t=' . filemtime('images/back.jpg') . '>'
                            :
                            // show empty place
                            '<div style="' . $styleaddon . 'width:' . $cardWidth . ';height:' . $cardHeight
                            . ';overflow:hidden;">&nbsp;</div>')) . '';
                    // '<img src="./images/blank2.jpg">'));
                }
                echo '</center></div>';
            }
        }
        echo '</nobr></div>';

        $tabledatahistory = array_reverse($tabledatahistory);
        // HISTORY
        foreach ($tabledatahistory as $eachHistory) {
            echo '<div class="historyTable" style="width:' . ($playersOnTable * $placeWidth) . '">';
            foreach ($playernames as $eachPlayerName) {
                if (time() - $players[$eachPlayerName] < IDLE_TIMEOUT_DELETE_SECONDS) {
                    echo '<div class="place"><p><i>' . $eachPlayerName . '<hr>' . '</i><center>';
                    $offsets = getCardOffset($eachHistory[$eachPlayerName]['guess'], $validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']], $_GET['theme']);
                    if (is_array($offsets)) {
                        // show nifty cards
                        echo '<div style="width:' . $cardWidth . ';height:' . $offsets[2] . ';background-image:url(\'themes/13plus1/std.png?1435657352'\');background-position:' . $offsets[0] . ' 0px;">&nbsp;</div>';
                    } else {
                        // theme not found or erroneous - show text cards
                        echo '<div class="card"><span style="height:' . $cardHeight
                            . 'px; width:1px; vertical-align:middle"></span>'
                            . $validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']][$eachHistory[$eachPlayerName]['guess']] . '</div>';
                    }
                    echo '</center></div>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    // echo '<pre>';

    exit;
}
$ID = session_id();


/**
 * @param $guess
 * @param $validOptions
 * @param $theme
 * @return string
 */
function getCardOffset($guess, $validOptions, $theme)
{
    $return = 0;
    $found = false;
    $imageName = 'storage/themes/' . $_SESSION['decksize'] . '/' . str_replace(array('/', '.'), '', $theme) . '.png';

    if (file_exists($imageName)) {
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($imageName);
        if ($img) {
            $width = imagesx($img);
            $cardWidth = $width / CARDS_IN_THEME;
            foreach ($validOptions as $key => $val) {
                if ($guess != $key) {
                    $return -= $cardWidth;
                } else {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$found) {
        return false;
    }
    return array($return . "px", $cardWidth, imagesy($img), $imageName . '?' . filemtime($imageName));
}

if (!isset($_GET['table'])) {

    $folder = 'themes/' . $_SESSION['decksize'] . '/';
    $otherfolder = 'themes/6plus1' . $_SESSION['secdecksize'] . '/';



    exit;
} else {


    // handle HTML page for the client
    ?>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Scrummy</title>

        <link href="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.9.43/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.9.43/js/mui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css">
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>



        <style>
            body {
                background-color: coral ;
            }

            .card {
                width: <?php echo $cardWidth; ?>px;
                height: <?php echo $cardHeight; ?>px;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-image: url('/storage/images/blank.jpg');
                background-size: <?php echo $cardWidth; ?>px auto;
                border: 0px solid red;
            }

            * {
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 8pt;
            }

            .currentTable {
                border: 0px solid black;
                background-image: url('storage/images/rw.png');
                height: <?php echo $placeHeight; ?>px;
            }

            .historyTable {
                border: 0px solid dotted;
                height: <?php echo $placeHeight; ?>px;
            }

            .place {
                border: 0px solid black;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                width: <?php echo $placeWidth; ?>px;
            }

            .currentTable .place {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }

            .historyTable .place {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }

            .header {
                border: 0px solid black;
                height: 25px;
                clear: both;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var TIMEOUT;
            var VALUE = "...";

            function statusCommand(cmd, user, table, options) {
                if (options == undefined) {
                    options = '';
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "?ID=<?php echo session_id(); ?>&ajax&name=" + user + "&table=" + table + "&" + cmd + "&options=" + options, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

            function showUser(str, name, table) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                }
                if (str != "..." && str != "AUTO") {
                    VALUE = str;
                    document.getElementById("guess").value = "...";
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                if (str == "AUTO") {
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "?theme=<?php echo $_GET['theme']; ?>&ID=<?php echo session_id(); ?>&ajax&table=" + table + "&name=" + name, true);
                } else {
                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "?theme=<?php echo $_GET['theme']; ?>&ID=<?php echo session_id(); ?>&ajax&table=" + table + "&guess=" + str + "&name=" + name, true);
                }
                xmlhttp.send();
                if (document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML != "Table does not exist.") {} else {
                    VALUE = "...";
                }
                timeout_init();
            }

            function timeout_init() {
                clearTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                TIMEOUT = setTimeout('showUser("AUTO","<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>","<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>")', 2000);
            }

            function initCards() {
                showUser("AUTO", "<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>", "<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>");
                timeout_init();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="initCards()">
        <?php
            for ($i = 8; $i > 0; $i--) {
                //echo '<img src="cards/E'.$i.'.png" width="50">';
            }
            //echo '<br>';
            ?>



        <form method="GET" onsubmit="javascript:return false;" class="mui-form">
            <?php
                if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
                    ?>
                <div class="mui-select">
                    <select id="guess" name="guess" onchange="showUser(this.value,'<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>','<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>')">
                        <option value="...">Select Your Card:</option>
                        <?php
                                foreach ($validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']] as $key => $val) {
                                    echo "<option value=\"" . $key . "\">" . $val . "</option>\n";
                                }
                                ?>
                    </select></div>


                <?php
                        foreach ($validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']] as $key => $val) {
                            $offsets = getCardOffset($key, $validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']], $_GET['theme']);
                            echo '<div class="place"><center><A href="javascript:showUser(\'' . $key . '\',\'' . $_GET['name']
                                . '\',\'' . $_GET['table'] . '\')">';
                            if (is_array($offsets)) {
                                // show nifty cards
                                echo '' .
                                    '<div style="width:' . $cardWidth . ';height:' . $cardHeight . ';background-image:url(\''.
                                     $offsets[3] . '\');background-position:' . $offsets[0] . ' 0px;">&nbsp;</div>';
                            } else {
                                // theme not found or erroneous - show text cards
                                echo '' .
                                    // show card face up
                                    '<div class="card"><span style="height:' . $cardHeight
                                    . 'px; width:1px; vertical-align:middle"></span>'
                                    . $validOptions[$_SESSION['decksize']][$tabledata[$eachPlayerName]['guess']] . '</div>';
                            }
                            echo '</A></center></div>';
                        }
                        echo '<br style="clear:both">';
                        //    echo '<A href="javascript:clearTimeout(TIMEOUT)">STOP REFRESH</A>';
                        ?>
            <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                <input name="message" size="100" onkeypress="statusCommand('message', '<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>', this.value)" onkeyup="statusCommand('message', '<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>', this.value)" onchange="statusCommand('message', '<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>', this.value)" onblur="statusCommand('message', '<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>', '<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>', this.value)">
            <?php
                }
                ?>
        </form>
        <br>
        <?php

            if ($admin) {
                echo '<mark>' . 'You`re the Scrumleader' . '</mark>' . '<br>';
                ?>
            <A href="javaScript:statusCommand('kill','<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>','<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>')">Reset</A> the current game
            <br>
            <A href="javaScript:statusCommand('add','<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>','<?php echo $_GET['table']; ?>')">New</A> Round? (Adds new game row)
            <br>
        <?php
            }
            ?>

        <div id="txtHint"><b>Cards are shown here</b></div>

    </body>

    </html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/227347/4) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like typical code from a Laravel project, though it sounds like that is what you are working towards. The HTML can be put into a blade template, and most of the logic can go into a controller (or multiple controllers if necessary). For handling the `$_GET['ajax']` requests - those should have a separate route - either in routes/web.php or routes/ajax.php.

The function `getCardOffset()` appears to return an array or a boolean when the file doesn't exist, the image can't be created from the png file or the width isn't found. The docblock claims it returns a string.

```
* @return string
```

It should be updated accordingly.

```
* @return array | boolean
```

The variable name `$return` could have a better name - like `$offset` or something that is significant to the background position.

---

In the JavaScript code the variable `TIMEOUT` is declared in all capitals. In idiomatic JavaScript, as is the case in many other c-based languages - that is a convention for constants, which are never re-assigned. The [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword can be used to declare a variable that is never re-assigned, though bear in mind [that does not mean it is immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#description).

---

The JS function `statusCommand` appears to check for `XMLHttpRequest` support- if the browser doesn't support it then it uses `ActiveXObject` for IE - is there a requirement to support IE? It is quite rare for that.

Also the callback for that request appears to be incomplete:

> ```
> xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
>     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
>
>     }
> }
> ```